# ¿Cómo puedo solucionar el error de la ausencia del uic en PyQt5?

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

[image: Error del Qt Designer al tratar de ver código]

Estoy trabajando con **Qt Designer**, y al momento de querer ver el código Python de la interfaz que he hecho (*View Code*), me genera ese mensaje de error mostrado en la imagen. Como ven tengo instalado PyQt5, no el 4 y tengo Python 3.6

Necesito saber cómo solucionar este error. Muchísimas Gracias

Comment: ¿Como has instalado Qt Designer?

Comment: Lo instalé por medio de un archivo que descargué de la página que es oficial, pero ahora no encuentro el link.

Comment: Qt Designer genera el código para c++ (eso es lo que hace de hecho uic), no para Python . Si quieres generar el código para Python has de usar pyuic5 de forma manual.

Comment: De qué forma? Desde cmd?

Comment: ¿Usas Windows verdad? Si te instalaste Qt Designed via  `pip install pyqt5-tools` (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyqt5-tools) deberías tenerlo. Ve a la carpeta de instalación de Python y ve a la carpeta `Scripts`, mira a ver si tienes `pyuic.exe` en ella. Confirma lo del sistema operativo y si lo tienes instalado y creo una respuesta si es necesario,

Comment: Si uso Windows, ejecutable no aparece en el script, pero trataré de instalar por el pip install a ver que tal. Gracias @FJSevilla

Comment: Jean he creado una respuesta por si te sirve de ayuda, un saludo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como te comenté Qt Designer vía `Form`-> `View code...` genera el código nativo para C++.

Si quieres genera el código para Python has de usar [**pyuic5**](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html#pyuic5).

Se instala junto a Qt Designer si usas el paquete [pyqt5-tools](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyqt5-tools) vía **pip**:

```
py -3.6 -m pip install pyqt5-tools
```

El ejecutable se encontrará en la carpeta Scripts dentro del directorio de instalación de Python 3.6 (`C:\Users\TuUsuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts` por ejemplo).

Si lo tienes agregado al PATH podrás llamarlo directamente abriendo la terminal. El uso básico es el siguiente (en el enlace de arriba tienes los argumentos disponibles):

```
C:\> pyuic5 mi_archivo.uic -o mi_archivo.py
```

En caso contrario usa la ruta absoluta al ejecutable:

```
C:\> C:\Users\TuUsuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts\pyuic5.exe mi_aechivo.ui -o mi_archivo.py
```

Donde `mi_archivo.ui` es la ruta al archivo generado por Qt Designer 
y `mi_archivo.py` la ruta al módulo Python que se va a generar. Lo más cómodo es situar la terminal en el directorio donde tienes guardado tu proyecto.

No es necesario obtener el archivo .py para trabajar con la interfaz desde Python, puedes cargar el fichero ui mediante `pyqt5.uic`:

```
from PyQt5 import uic, QtWidgets

class MyDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyDialog, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi('my_dialog.ui', self)
        self.show()
```

Comment: Muchiiiiisiimas gracias @FJSevilla fuiste de gran y valiosa ayuda!!!. De verdad muchas gracias, califico tu respuesta como **Más que Excelente**.